# ThreadStateException was unhandled by user code in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to write a C# Form that is able to read in from a file and am receiving a `ThreadStateException`.

Here is my Utility class, where the error is occuring.

```
public static class Utility {
    public static bool ExecuteWithTimeLimit(TimeSpan timeSpan, Action codeBlock) {
        try {
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();
            Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => codeBlock());
            task.Wait(timeSpan);
            sw.Stop();
            Handler.Log(String.Format("Total Runtime: {0} mins, {1} seconds.{2}{2}", sw.Elapsed.Minutes, sw.Elapsed.Seconds.ToString(), Environment.NewLine));
            return task.IsCompleted;
        } catch (AggregateException ae) {
            throw ae.InnerExceptions[0];
        }
    }

    public static List<String> ReadFile()
    {
        OpenFileDialog _FileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        _FileDialog.Filter = "CSV File (*.csv)|*.csv";

        //Error Occurring on the below line.
        if (_FileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
            List<String> list = new List<String>();
            try
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(_FileDialog.FileName);
                string line;
                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    line = reader.ReadLine();
                    list.AddRange(line.Split(','));
                }
                reader.Close();
                return list;
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { return null; }
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

The error is occurring on this line...

`if (_FileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {`

Below is my main method where the function is being called.

```
static class Program {
    //Limit to a 5 minute runtime.
    private static int TotalExecuteTime = 300000;

    [STAThread]
    static void Main() {
        Handler.CreateLog();
        bool CompletedExecution = Utility.ExecuteWithTimeLimit(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(TotalExecuteTime), () => {
            List<String> WordList = Utility.ReadFile();
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        });
        Handler.OpenLog();
    }
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: codeBlock is implemented on this line: 
`Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => codeBlock());`

Comment: What is the message in the exception?

Comment: @TechieBee The message is as follows...  
System.Windows.Forms.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Current thread must be set to single thread apartment (STA) mode before OLE calls can be made. Ensure that your Main function has STAThreadAttribute marked on it. This exception is only raised if a debugger is attached to the process.

Comment: you need to create an STA thread that launches the dialog .

Comment: @TechieBee How do I do that?

Comment: Check the answer & lemme know if it works,coz its not tested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this `_FileDialog.ShowDialog()` to `STAShowDialog(_FileDialog)`.

Add these helper method & class for work around :

```
 /* STAShowDialog takes a FileDialog and shows it on a background STA thread and returns the results.*/
    private DialogResult STAShowDialog(FileDialogdialog)
    {
            DialogState state = new DialogState();
            state.dialog = dialog;
            System.Threading.Thread t = new System.Threading.Thread(state.ThreadProcShowDialog);
            t.SetApartmentState(System.Threading.ApartmentState.STA);
            t.Start();
            t.Join();
            return state.result;
    }



/* Helper class to hold state and return value in order to call FileDialog.ShowDialog on a background thread.*/
   public class DialogState
  {
    public DialogResultresult;
    public FileDialogdialog;
    public voidThreadProcShowDialog()
    {
        result = dialog.ShowDialog();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Works brilliantly. Thank you.